# Pseudo Sound Bars for Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, animation, audio, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to add `.gif` file to `xaml` image source ?

I would like to know if an animation like the image below is possible using `xaml` or `C#`

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a WebView for that. Or you can also use the following plugin: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-Awesome-Controls/tree/master/GifImageView